# If User is NOT Logged in and Page ID is not 6 - Redirect to Login

Tags: redirect, login

I am trying to redirect users based on the following...

- If Role = Customer & Page Is NOT ID 6 Then Redirect To Checkout
- If Not Logged in & Page Is Not ID 6 then redirect to login
- User role = member and Page ID is 6 redirect to home page

  ```
  //If Role = Customer & Page Is ID 6 Then Redirect To Checkout
  if ( user_can( $current_user, "customer" ) && ! is_page( 6 ) ) 
  {
  wp_redirect(home_url().'/checkout');
  exit;
  }

  elseif ( ! is_page ( 6 ) )
  {
  //If Not Logged in & Page Is Not ID 6 then redirect to login
  auth_redirect();
  }


  elseif ( user_can( $current_user, "member" ) && is_page( 6 ) )
  {
  // User role = member and Page ID is 6 redirect to home page
  wp_redirect(home_url());
  exit;
  }
  ?>
  ```

Which as far as I can see should work, but its not, it gives me a blank page.  The script is being run from header.php and is the first thing in the PHP file.

The first rule - If Role = Customer & Page Is ID 6 Then Redirect To Checkout works correctly and they are redirected to the checkout page.

The second rule prevents anybody from logging in

The third rule works correctly

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

You are using [`auth_redirect();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect), by default it checks if a user is logged in or not, so you don't need to check again if a user is logged in or not

> When this code is called from a page, it checks to see if the user viewing the page is logged in. If the user is not logged in, they are redirected to the login page. The user is redirected in such a way that, upon logging in, they will be sent directly to the page they were originally trying to access.

So you can just do

```
if ( ! is_page ( 6 ) ) {
    auth_redirect();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
//If Role = Customer & Page Is ID 6 Then Redirect To Checkout
if ( user_can( $current_user, "customer" ) && ! is_page( 6 ) )
```

This is your code's first two lines, check line one *Page Is ID 6* and check line 2 *`! is_page( 6 )`*. Spot the difference?

Your code in line 2 says *if the page ID **IS NOT** 6*

**EDIT 3**

> The script is being run from header.php and is the first thing in the PHP file

What do you mean the first thing in the php file. This will break you site. You will need to move this code to at least within the opening body tag (`<body>`), where it should be

**EDIt 4**

Since we started, a few thing changed :-). Try to re-organise your sequence

```
//If Role = Customer & Page Is ID 6 Then Redirect To Checkout
if ( user_can( $current_user, "customer" ) && ! is_page( 6 ) ) {

    wp_redirect(home_url().'/checkout');
  exit;

}elseif ( user_can( $current_user, "member" ) && is_page( 6 ) {

   // User role = member and Page ID is 6 redirect to home page
     wp_redirect(home_url());
  exit;

} elseif ( ! is_page ( 6 ) && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
//If Not Logged in & Page Is Not ID 6 then redirect to login
     auth_redirect(); //Not sure if this will work. 
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi,I have tried amending things but it still isn't working for me.  Curiously, any page on my site that has the number 6 anywhere in the title is also blank.  Connected?

Comment: Getting tired, mind a bit lazy, lol. Check my update

Comment: Good point, I have changed it again but it is still not working as expected.  I have updated my original post with my current code

Comment: are you published the page which have ID 6? if page is in draft or trash then it'll not work.

Comment: Yep, page is published and live

Comment: See my update @fightstarr20

Comment: I did but there is still no change.  I have updated my original post again with some details on where this is running from in the page, maybe that might help?

Comment: The first rule works correctly - The Second Rule Prevents Anybody From Logging In - the Third Rule Works Correctly

Comment: Check my update

Comment: I have tried it there already, it made no difference.  Really confused

Comment: Check my last update, unfortunately I'm off to bed within the next 5 min. :-)

Comment: Just had a light bulb moment.  As this script is being run in the header, does it even know what pageid 6 is?

Comment: Yes, it should know

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in your `header.php` and pollute your templates, make use of the system WordPress offers you and hook into the [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action like this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse156774_redirect' );
function wpse156774_redirect() {
    // your code and conditions here
}
```

This can be put into your `functions.php` or a plugin.